# How do I publish a game I made in Mathematica so that anyone can play it who is unfamiliar with Mathematica?

Tags: deployment, game

I'm trying to figure out how to publish a game so a friend can play it by just providing a link to it. Is that possible or do they have to have an account or be tech savvy?

Comment: You can try and see if you can get it to run in [CDF Player](https://www.wolfram.com/player/), which anyone can download.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, you can't make it a widget?

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, see here: https://mathematica.wolframcloud.com/env/bruin/Published/puzzle.cdf